# Filter ng-options conditionally with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter ng-options based on ng-model.

this is a preview of the contactsModal array

```
contactsModal = [
  {
    "account" : {
        "id" : 1
    },
    "first_name" : "Test"
  },
  {
    "account" : {
        "id" : 2
    },
    "first_name" : "Test 2"
  }
];
```

this is my list

```
<select 
ng-model="activityAddForm.contact_id" 
ng-options="contact.id as (contact.first_name+' '+contact.last_name) for contact in contactsModal | filter:contact.account.id==activityAddForm.account_id track by contact.id">
   <option value="">Choisir...</option>
</select>
```

and the model used for the condition

```
<select 
ng-model="activityAddForm.account_id"
...
```

I want to show contacts with the same account.id like activityAddForm.account_id

I've tried with this line but not working.

```
 | filter:contact.account.id==activityAddForm.account_id
```

Any help ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you include the structure of the data you are trying to filter? An example of the blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ng-options="contact.id as (contact.first_name+' '+contact.last_name) for contact in 
filteredContacts = ( contactsModal | filter:{'account':{'id':activityAddForm.account_id}}:true) track by contact.id"
```

Safe Way:

```
app.filter('filterContact', ['$filter',function($filter) {
     return function(list, value) {
       return $filter('filter')(list, function(val, key){
            return val.account.id == value;
       })
     };
 }]);


//and your ng-option

ng-options="contact.id as (contact.first_name+' '+contact.last_name) for contact in 
contactsModal | filterContact:activityAddForm.account_id track by contact.id
```

Comment: list is still not filtered :s

Comment: contactsModal list is empty with that

Comment: `return function(list, account) {
        return $filter('filter')(list, function(val, key){

            if(account) {
                if(val.account.id === account.id){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

    };`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
| filter:{ account: {id: activityAddForm.account_id } }
```

Comment: I tried but same result the list is not filtered, i've tried | filter:{ contact: { account: {id: activityAddForm.account_id } } } and now the list is empty